# If the Dirac equation describes charged particles, why is its charge density always positive?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, charge, dirac-equation, antimatter

Its charge density is $\psi^\dagger (x) \psi (x)$. This thing is positive for both positive and negative energy Dirac fields. If the charge density is positive, then the total charge is also positive.

So I think this doesn't deserve to be called the "charge density"? This quantity is more in line with the probability density from Non-Relativistic QM.

Also, after quantising the Dirac field, the operator corresponding to this "probability density" should be the particle number operator, shouldn't it? But, somehow, the corresponding operator is the charge operator.

Comment: You should clarify your notations. As it is, it looks like you're confusing charge density and probability density (which you probably aren't, given your second paragraph). What is $\psi$? A bispinor?

Comment: @Miyase Yes. It is a bispinor. Did the first experssion I wrote not the one of charge density? If yes, what's the expression of charge density?

Comment: My memories on the subject are remote so I won't go any further than a comment, but I don't think I ever saw $\psi^\dagger\psi$ being interpreted as a *charge* density. It doesn't even have the correct unit for that.

Comment: @Miyase I just checked from an independent source. Its current density is $\psi ' \gamma ^{\mu} \psi$, where $\psi ' =\psi ^{\dagger} \gamma ^0$. Charge density is the first component of the current, that is, $\psi ^{\dagger} \gamma ^0 \gamma ^0 \psi=\psi ^{\dagger} \psi $

Comment: Yes, that looks legit... Next problem that comes to mind: you seem to try to identify a classical quantity (density charge) and a quantum one ($\psi^\dagger\psi$). It may not be as direct as it sounds, especially since the bispinor contains the positron *and* the electron. If I find something more concrete, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what could be an answer in Peskin & Schroeder chapter 3, "Quantization of the Dirac field" and, for online reading, something similar [here](https://www.weizmann.ac.il/particle/perez/Courses/QMII19/TA11%20-%20Dirac.pdf).

After quantization, the charge is:
$$Q=\int d^3x\,\psi^\dagger\psi\propto N_p-N_e$$
where $N_p$ is the number of positrons and $N_e$ the number of electrons. This quantity may be negative, since $\psi$ and $\psi^\dagger$ are operators, not numbers.

So $\psi^\dagger\psi$ may be interpreted as the sum of the charge densities for positrons and electrons.

Comment: I just find it weird that this quantity, prior to quantisation, can't be interpreted as a charge because it's always positive. But after quantisation, its corresponding operator can be interpreted as a charge.  I think I should just accept it.

Comment: This is the old "complementarity" problem, made more difficult because basic fields in QFT include both particles and antiparticles. Historically, complementarity was a way to use known physics (classical) to interpret new physics (quantum). There was no proof, it was just for lack of something better: there's no reason to assume that there should always be a direct correspondence from classical to quantum.